# Вычисление заработной платы по условиям

Tags: excel, условия

Необходимо реализовать условия под номером 5
Написала это, но выкидывает ошибку. В чем проблема?

```
=ЕСЛИ(B12<5000;1000;если(B12>5000 и B12<10000;1000+(B12*1/100);если(B12>10000 и B12<20000;1000+(B12*1,5/100);если(B12>20000;1000+(B12*2/100); 000))))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почитай cправку про функцию `И`, синтаксис неправильный `B12>5000 и B12<10000`

Comment: ну и в принципе условие `B12>5000` лишнее, можно одним `B12<10000` обойтись

Answer (score 1):

```
=ЕСЛИ(B12<5000;1000;ЕСЛИ(B12<=10000;1000+B12*1%;ЕСЛИ(B12<=20000;1000+B12*1,5%;1000+B12*2%)))

=1000+B12*ЕСЛИ(B12<5000;;ЕСЛИ(B12<=10000;1%;ЕСЛИ(B12<=20000;1,5%;2%)))

=1000+B12*ВПР(B12;{0;0:5000;1:10001;1,5:20001;2};2)/100

=1000+B12*ПРОСМОТР(B12;{0;5000;10001;20001};{0;1;1,5;2})/100
```

Но. если судить по тексту задания, нужно составить таблицу.

Первый столбец - граничные значения, начиная с нуля, второй столбец - процент. Определение процента:

```
=1000+B12*ВПР(B12;C2:D5;2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Исправленная формула:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B12<5000;1000;ЕСЛИ(И(B12>=5000;B12<10000);1000+(B12*1/100);ЕСЛИ(И(B12>=10000;B12<20000);1000+(B12*1,5/100);ЕСЛИ(B12>=20000;1000+(B12*2/100); 0))))
```

Как написал бы я:

```
=ЕСЛИ(B12>=20000;1000+B12*0,02;ЕСЛИ(B12>=10000;1000+B12*0,015;ЕСЛИ(B12>=5000;1000+B12*0,01;1000)))
```

Answer (score 0):

спасибо уже сделала!

```
=ЕСЛИ(B2<5000;1000;ЕСЛИ(И(B2>5000;B2<10000);1000+(B2*1/100);ЕСЛИ(И(B2>10000;B2<20000);1000+(B2*1,5/100);ЕСЛИ(B2>20000;1000+(B2*2/100); 0))))
```

Comment: Не нужны И, ведь одна граница уже проверена в предыдущей функции. В Вашей формуле граничное значение (например 10000) никуда не попадает и при такой сумме получите ноль. А вообще, нуля в формуле быть не должно - по задаче: захватывается весь диапазон - от до 500 (т.е. от 0) и свыше 20000.